# Why does FINDSTR behave differently in powershell and cmd?

Tags: regex, powershell, windows-7, cmd, findstr

The following command pipes the output of `echo` to `findstr` and tries to match a regular expression with it. I use it to check if the echoed line only consists of (one or more) digits:

```
echo 123 | findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9]*$"
```

The expected output of `findstr` is `123`, which means that the expression could be matched with this string. The output is correct when I execute the command with `powershell.exe`.
Executing the command in `cmd.exe` however does not give a match. It only outputs an empty line and sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 1, which means that no match was found.
What causes the different behavior? Is there a way to make this command run correctly on cmd as well?

My OS is Windows 7 Professional, 64 Bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Powershell the command echoes the string `123` to the pipeline and that matches your regular expression.

In cmd, your command echos `123<space>` to the pipeline. The trailing space isn't allowed for in your regular expression so you don't get a match.

Try:

```
echo 123| findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9]*$"
```

and it will work just fine. Or just switch entirely to Powershell and stop having to worry about the vagaries of `cmd.exe`.

*Edit:*
Yes, cmd and powershell handle parameters very differently.

With cmd all programs are passed a simple text command line. The processing that cmd performs is pretty minimal: it will terminate the command at `|` or `&`, removes i/o redirection and will substitute in any variables. Also of course it identifies the command and executes it. Any argument processing is done by the command itself, so a command can choose whether spaces separate arguments or what `"` characters mean. Mostly commands have a fairly common interpretation of these things but they can just do their own thing with the string they were given. `echo` does it's own thing.

Powershell on the other hand has a complex syntax for arguments. All of the argument parsing is done by Powershell. The parsed arguments are then passed to Powershell functions or cmdlets as a sequence of .Net objects: that means you aren't limited to just passing simple strings around. If the command turns out not to be a powershell command and runs externally it will attempt to convert the objects into a string and puts quotes round any arguments that have a space. Sometimes the conversion can be a bit confusing, but it does mean that something like this:

```
echo (1+1)
```

will echo `2` in Powershell where cmd would just echo the input string.

It is worth always remembering that with Powershell you are working with objects, so for example:

```
PS C:\> echo Today is (get-date)
Today
is

17 April 2014 20:03:15


PS C:\> echo "Today is $(get-date)"
Today is 04/17/2014 20:03:20
```

In the first case `echo` gets 3 objects, two strings and a date. It outputs each object on a separate line (and a blank line when the type changes). In the second case it gets a single object which is a string (and unlike the cmd `echo` it never sees the quote marks).

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. But why does echo behave differently then? Does cmd handle parameters differently than powershell?

Comment: @maddin45 Added some description of how parameters are handled.

Comment: Wow, I guess PowerShell actually deserves its name. Thank you for the thorough explaination!  If I could I would vote this answer up again :) I think I will look into the features of PowerShell a bit more, this seems to be really useful.